# Simple Ajax jQuery get method not completing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my first use of Ajax.  Here is the script I am trying to run:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    alert("on document ready");
    $(document).click(function(e){
        alert("inside click handler");
        $.get("runner.php", function(data) {
           alert("get method has completed");
        });
    }); 
});
```

The alerts: "on document ready" and "inside click handler" all display correctly but I cannot get the alert inside the $.get method to display.  Also, the runner.php file is in the same directory as the JavaScript file.  I eventually want to get information from the runner.php file but I cannot even make this $.get method complete.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, but this example was taken almost directly from the jQuery manual.

Comment: What do you intend `function(data)` to do?

Comment: Check your browser console. Does it request the URL? What does it return?

Comment: Pop open your dev. console and see what it says.

Comment: If `runner.php` returns a failure, the alert will not display. What's inside the function is only executed when a success message is returned.

Comment: trojansdestroy, I want the function to eventually return data that has queried a database. Jack, I am on a server. @Izzey I'm not quite sure where to look in the console to see if it requests.

Comment: Check with firebug or ie developer toolbar if the url is right, and if so check the request and response, you have a net tab on both that trace the request

Comment: If you are using `file://` instead of a real `http://` (by localhost or even live server) to make ajax, it WILL fail.

Comment: I finally found it in my google developer console.  The path was relative to the page that the script was loaded from.  I through it would be relative to the js file itself.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing an absolute url to `runner.php`, so `/js/runner.php` or `/runner.php` whichever directory it's in.

Also if you have firebug installed, you can use it to view what the problem is. If it's telling you `404 Not Found` then you will need to place the absolute url as I just mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow this pattern:

```
$.get("runner.php", function() {
  alert("success");
})
.done(function() { alert("second success"); })
.fail(function() { alert("error"); })
.always(function() { alert("finished"); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Where are these files? Are they on a web server or on your local computer? I had the same problem before and the reason being I was trying to access a file that was located on my local computer so I would always get an error

[AJAX request using jQuery does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386595/ajax-request-using-jquery-does-not-work)

I fixed it by setting up a local web server and the same code worked beautifully :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery 1.8 or later, then you need to use the `fail()` function to report errors with your call to your PHP, like this:

```
.get("runner.php", function() {
    alert("success");
})
.fail(function() { 
    alert("An error happened, check PHP script for problems."); 
})
```

Note: jQuery 1.8 deprecated the `error` callback and replaced it with the `.fail()` function.

Comment: I fixed the issue, but the fail function is handy for future implementations, thanks!

Comment: Great, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of nothing happening on the callback is a 404 or 500 error. As with a few other answers, make sure to add a fail listener to your `$.get` request and you can `console.log(data);` to determine what's going wrong on the server side.