# Getting CORS policy error on loading font in three.js for TextGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am learning three.js. I tried to display some text but I am getting CORS policy access blocked error on loading the font file. I have checked if the path passed is correct, tried putting the file in various locations, but still nothing. Here is my code to load the text:

```
var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader.load('../Libraries/three.js-master/examples/fonts/gentilis_bold.typeface.json', function(font) {

  var geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry('Hello three.js!', {
    font: font,
    size: 80,
    height: 1,
    curveSegments: 12,
    bevelEnabled: true,
    bevelThickness: 10,
    bevelSize: 8,
    bevelOffset: 0,
    bevelSegments: 5
  });
});
```

And the error I am getting is:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'file:///A:/Code/IIITH/computer-graphics-iiith/SRIP/Libraries/three.js-master/examples/fonts/gentilis_bold.typeface.json'
>   from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https.

Can I please get help resolving this error? I am still learning three.js and don't know it in detail. What mistake am I making?

Comment: In your browsers address bar, do you see `file://`?  You can't do ajax calls if you server over the `file://` protocol.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File Protocol Ajax Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265680/file-protocol-ajax-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not related with Three.js.

It's a security measurement implemented by browsers to protect the users from multiple threats. You can find more details about how it works in this post:

["Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." error when loading a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local)

---

This is how Three.js suggests that you deal with this restriction: [How to run things locally](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally)